# RainbowKit - Custom authentication not verifying

Tags: rainbowkit

I am implementing a custom authentication by **createAuthenticationAdapter()** from [RainbowKit](https://www.rainbowkit.com/) following the docs https://www.rainbowkit.com/docs/custom-authentication

The message to sign  (login) shows perfectly, but it freezes on the verification step even if I return true. What am I missing?

[image]

```
verify: async ({ message, signature }) => {
      console.log(message, signature);
      const siweMessage = new SiweMessage(message);
      const { data, error, success } = await siweMessage.verify({ signature });
      console.log(data, success, error);
      return true;
   }
```

Here is my complete code

```
import { createAuthenticationAdapter } from "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit";
import { SiweMessage, generateNonce } from "siwe";

export const authenticationAdapter = createAuthenticationAdapter({
   getNonce: async () => {
      return generateNonce();
   },

   createMessage: ({ nonce, address, chainId }) => {
      return new SiweMessage({
         domain: window.location.host,
         address,
         statement: "This transaction does not have any cost",
         uri: window.location.origin,
         version: "1",
         chainId,
         nonce,
      });
   },

   getMessageBody: ({ message }) => {
      console.log(message);
      return message.prepareMessage();
   },

   verify: async ({ message, signature }) => {
      console.log(message, signature);
      const siweMessage = new SiweMessage(message);
      const { data, error, success } = await siweMessage.verify({ signature });
      console.log(data, success, error);
      return true;
   },

   signOut: async () => {
      await fetch("/api/auth/logout");
   },
});
```

Comment: Sadly no points to comment. Same issue here. Had any luck resolving it? The interface says "boolean" on Promise, so true/false should work. export interface AuthenticationAdapter<Message> { getNonce: () => Promise<string>; createMessage: (args: { nonce: string; address: string; chainId: number; }) => Message; getMessageBody: (args: { message: Message; }) => string; verify: (args: { message: Message; signature: string; }) => Promise<boolean>; signOut: () => Promise<void>;}

Comment: @Rivara, thanks for commenting, I forgot to update a solution for this problem I had some time ago

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question, hope that it helps anyone that faced the same problem.

I managed to play around a bit when I needed to solve and came to a solution, maybe not the best, but it's working.

It seems we need to literally **change the status of the context within Rainbow**, as described [here](https://www.rainbowkit.com/docs/custom-authentication#providing-the-authentication-state) in the comments below.

```
  // You'll need to resolve AUTHENTICATION_STATUS here
  // using your application's authentication system.
  // It needs to be either 'loading' (during initial load),
  // 'unauthenticated' or 'authenticated'.
```

I also placed my authentication logic really close to rainbowkit provider so that I could easily change the status in a React state. Here is my full code

```
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<AuthenticationStatus>("unauthenticated");
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType>({} as UserType);
  const { reload, push } = useRouter();

  async function signIn() {
    const { "application.token": token } = parseCookies();
    if (typeof token === "undefined") return;
    const { data } = await axios.get<UserType>("/api/profile/user-profile");
    setUser(data);
    setStatus("authenticated"); **// changing this status made the flow work**
  }

  async function signOut() {
    setStatus("unauthenticated");
    destroyCookie({}, "application.token", {
      path: "/",
    });
    reload();
  }

  async function handleSetUser(data: UserType) {
    setUser(data);
  }

  const authenticationAdapter = createAuthenticationAdapter({
    getNonce: async () => {
      return generateNonce();
    },

    createMessage: ({ nonce, address, chainId }) => {
      return new SiweMessage({
        domain: window.location.host,
        address,
        statement: "This transaction does not have any cost",
        uri: window.location.origin,
        version: "1",
        chainId,
        nonce,
      });
    },

    getMessageBody: ({ message }) => {
      return message.prepareMessage();
    },

    verify: async ({ message, signature }) => {
      try {
        setStatus("loading");
        const { data } = await axios.post<IVerifyResponse>("/api/auth/verify", {
          message,
          signature,
        });
        setCookie(null, "application.token", data.access_token, {
          path: "/",
        });
        if (data.access_token) setStatus("authenticated");
        await signIn();
        return data.ok;
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error("Some error occurred");
        return false;
      }
    },

    signOut: async () => {
      setStatus("unauthenticated");
      destroyCookie({}, "application.token", {
        path: "/",
      });
      push("/");
    },
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
    signIn();
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) return null;
  return (
    <WagmiConfig client={cliente}>
      <RainbowKitAuthenticationProvider adapter={authenticationAdapter} status={status}>
        <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains}>
          <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, handleSetUser, signOut }}>
            {children}
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </RainbowKitProvider>
      </RainbowKitAuthenticationProvider>
    </WagmiConfig>
  );
```

The **WagmiConfig** and **RainbowKit** simple configurations can be found [here](https://www.rainbowkit.com/docs/installation)